# Uniquely Identify Flash content

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, flash

I have a dynamic page (say myFlashContainer.jsp) which renders different Flash content based on which link was clicked.

Now the code which renders the Flash is rendered as follows;

```
<object height="100%" align="l" width="100%" id="player" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,24,0" classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000">
<param value="always" name="allowScriptAccess">
<param value="player.swf" name="movie">
<param value="high" name="quality">
<param value="transparent" name="wmode">
<param value="" name="bgcolor">
<param value="exactfit" name="scale">
<param value="tl" name="salign">
<param value="false" name="menu">
<param value="" name="FlashVars">
<embed height="100%" align="l" width="100%" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" flashvars="" menu="false" salign="tl" name="player" bgcolor="" wmode="transparent" scale="exactfit" quality="high" src="player.swf">
</object>
```

Now the Flash content is not actually created by me, but by some third-part vendor.
I am more into UI development (HTML/CSS/JS)

So my question is how does different Flash content appear given that all pages use "player.swf" as the value.

Is there some kind of scripting which makes it possible ? If yes, what should I look for in the code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [Flash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Flash) player can be a complex program. Like PHP or Javascript it can load content dynamically. Check out the wikipedia article about it.

Comment: Yes, it can be...But my simple question is how does it identify just by clicking on a link ? I mean where should I look for the parameter passing ?

Comment: What kind of link do you mean? Are they outside the flash or inside? If outside: Do they load an new page or do they have a Javascript event? You can make Javascript calles to a flash object.

Answer (score 1):

The data might be sent using GET-like array (`player.swf?param1=value1&param2=value2`) in the src attribute and maybe the movie param.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find out how your third party swf actually works and what kind of interaction it expects. There are several ways that player.swf could have been programmed. Using [Flashvars](http://blogs.adobe.com/pdehaan/2006/07/using_flashvars_with_actionscr.html) is the more common way to have  different load settings, but the .swf could also be calling a javascript function of yours.

You need to find out how you're suposed to interact with their swf.

So depending on the clicked link, you would set up the flash container differently (change the flashvar parameters, the javascript function or even something else)

Comment: Thx a lot...so when u say Flashvars mostly, if u see i have pasted the generated code in my original question which has blank value for Flashvars...so does that mean in my case, it might be a different strategy....

Comment: The flashvars are optional variables just like args in a main function. Just because you're not sending them in doesn't mean they wouldn't be used if you were. Try to find out how the player works.

Comment: Ok..Thx again....Actually from my side, I only have the .swf and not the source .fla with me...So is it possible to still analyze the working and if you could very briefly let me know how it can be done...

Comment: Can you not ask how it was made? Does it not have documentation? Has it never been used before? If none of these, you could try and decompile it, just do a search on this site and you will find a lot of  answers explaining.